# How to use queryselectorall in addevent listener

Tags: javascript

when i click the left button that other right button must be active,then  i do the same for the right button it should work,i acheived this using queryselector but when i duplicate the same element,this same code wont work,is there any way i can use queryselectorall to acheive this,thanks.

```js
(function() {
  const slick_prev_button = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
  const slick_next_button = document.querySelector('.next-button');
  const slick_left_button_background = document.querySelector('.left-arrow-color');
  const slick_right_button_background = document.querySelector('.right-arrow-color');


  slick_prev_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slick_left_button_background.classList.remove('left-arrow-color');
    slick_left_button_background.classList.add('left-arrow-color-active');
    slick_right_button_background.classList.remove('right-arrow-color-active');
    slick_right_button_background.classList.add('right-arrow-color');
  });

  slick_next_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slick_left_button_background.classList.remove('left-arrow-color-active');
    slick_left_button_background.classList.add('left-arrow-color');
    slick_right_button_background.classList.remove('right-arrow-color');
    slick_right_button_background.classList.add('right-arrow-color-active');
  });
})();
```

```css
.dual-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.left-arrow-colour i {
  color: #f67b54;
  background: #efefef;
}

.left-arrow-colour-active i {
  color: #efefef;
  background: #f67b54;
}

.right-arrow-colour i {
  color: #f67b54;
  background: #efefef;
}

.right-arrow-colour-active i {
  color: #efefef;
  background: #f67b54;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dual-button">
  <button class="prev-button left-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-left "></i></button>
  <button class="next-button right-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-right "></i></button>
</div>

<div class="dual-button">
  <button class="prev-button left-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-left "></i></button>
  <button class="next-button right-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-right "></i></button>
</div>

<div class="dual-button">
  <button class="prev-button left-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-left "></i></button>
  <button class="next-button right-arrow-colour"><i class=" fas fa-angle-right "></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call your code on the parent element like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dual-button').forEach(function(parentEl) {
    const prev = parentEl.querySelector('.prev-button');
    const next = parentEl.querySelector('.next-button');
    prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.remove('left-arrow-color');
        this.classList.add('left-arrow-color-active');
        next.classList.remove('right-arrow-color-active');
        next.classList.add('right-arrow-color');
    });

    next.addEventListener('click', function() {
        prev.classList.add('left-arrow-color');
        prev.classList.remove('left-arrow-color-active');
        this.classList.add('right-arrow-color-active');
        this.classList.remove('right-arrow-color');
    });
});
```

Also, judging by your css classes you can probably simplify that a lot since you are using the same style rules for the same css classes multiple times (e.g. you could just make a `.button-inactive` and `.button-active` class. Or even better, just a `.active` class. The inactive state would then just be the default style on the `button` element).